# Error: Unable to load gfortran compiled DLL in R ("symbol name not in load table")

Tags: r, windows, dll, fortran

Well, I recently fell in love with `Fortran` (`f90`) and have been trying to understand the "kung-fu" of `R` and `Fortran`. I found several relevant and helpful questions here (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731807/r-fortran-call) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021991/creating-dll-with-gfortran-on-windows)).

**What I am trying to do:**

I am (probably, trying to do something crazy) trying to call the following `.f90` subroutines in `R` (x64) using `.Fortran()` function. Here is the `test.f90` code:

```
! Computes the square of a number

Subroutine sr1(a,b)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sr1
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'sr1' :: sr1

implicit none
integer a,b
b = a*a
End Subroutine sr1

! Computes the cube of a number
Subroutine sr2(x,y)   
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sr2
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'sr2' :: sr2

implicit none
integer x,y
y = x*x*x
End Subroutine sr2
```

I am compiling the above `test.f90` code via `gfortran` on my Windows 10 machine by:

```
gfortran -shared -o test.dll test.f90
```

The compilation works and I get the `test.dll`. Now, in `R`. I try to load it:

```
 dyn.load("path_to_file/test.dll")
```

It works. But, it fails here:

```
> is.loaded("test")
[1] False
```

I already found a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767463/fortran-symbol-not-in-load-table-unable-to-call-loaded-symbol-in-r). But, I could not get the clue to fix my problem. Can someone suggest some workaround to fix the issue?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a tag for a specific version for version-specific questions, but your question is not version-specific. Note that Fortran 90 is very old and obsolete. Also note there is no need for a `return` in every function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I just edited the code. In addition to the suggestions to fix the problem, I was also interested to know whether this error is reproducible, somehow.

Comment: To be clear, the returns do not fix anything, they are just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a big user of R, but my tests show that while

```
is.loaded("test_R")
```

indeed returns `FALSE`, both

```
is.loaded("sr1")
```

and

```
is.loaded("sr2")
```

return `TRUE`. But I did my tests on Linux and GCC which may interpret the extrnally visible subroutine names differently.

Comment: That is, `is.loaded()` asks about a symbol in a shared object, not the library's name.

Comment: Thanks both of you. is.loaded("sr1") also returns TRUE and solved the problem.